# How to construct a table from a t-test in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, t-test

I was provided with three t-tests:

```
Two Sample t-test

data:  cammol by gender
t = -3.8406, df = 175, p-value = 0.0001714
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.11460843 -0.03680225
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       2.318132        2.393837 


Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  alkphos by gender
t = -2.9613, df = 145.68, p-value = 0.003578
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -22.351819  -4.458589
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       85.81319        99.21839 


Two Sample t-test

data:  phosmol by gender
t = -3.4522, df = 175, p-value = 0.0006971
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.14029556 -0.03823242
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       1.059341        1.148605
```

And I want to construct a table with these t-test results in R markdown like:
[wanted_table_format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5DvZ.png)

I've tried reading some instructions for using "knitr" and "kable" functions, but honestly, I do not know how to apply the t-test results to those functions.

What could I do?

Comment: Try with `broom::tidy`

Comment: I'm a newbie to this R language, so please don't go mad if I say something dumb:

Comment: I noticed that broom and tidy weren't installed on my R, so I tried doing install.packages(broom), but the program says: "object broom not found"

Comment: You need `install.packages("broom")` with quotes

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like? Which statistics do you wish to output? You can see how to access them using `str(x)` where `x` is your object. This will tell you the structure and names of elements (such as `x$conf.int`, `x$statistic`, `x$parameter`, `x$p.value`, `x$estimate`).

Comment: Uh, silly mistake... in order to make a table, I first have to take the t-test above as an input.. right..? like ( test <- "something" ) If I have to, how can I take those t-tests as inputs?

Comment: Or is there a manual way to construct a table?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your three t-tests are saved as `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`.

```
t1 <- t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100)
t2 <- t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 1))
t3 <- t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 2))
```

You could turn them into one data frame (that can then be printed as a table) with the broom and purrr packages:

```
library(broom)
library(purrr)

tab <- map_df(list(t1, t2, t3), tidy)
```

On the above data, this would become:

```
     estimate    estimate1   estimate2  statistic      p.value parameter   conf.low  conf.high
1  0.07889713 -0.008136139 -0.08703327   0.535986 5.925840e-01  193.4152 -0.2114261  0.3692204
2 -0.84980010  0.132836627  0.98263673  -6.169076 3.913068e-09  194.2561 -1.1214809 -0.5781193
3 -1.95876967 -0.039048940  1.91972073 -13.270232 3.618929e-29  197.9963 -2.2498519 -1.6676875
                   method alternative
1 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
2 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
3 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
```

Some of the columns probably don't matter to you, so you could do something like this to get just the columns you want:

```
tab[c("estimate", "statistic", "p.value", "conf.low", "conf.high")]
```

---

As noted in the comments, you'd have to first do `install.packages("broom")` and `install.packages("purrr")`.

Comment: is there a way to add a column showing which t-test the output came from t1, t2 or t3? Also how do you reduce the number of sig figs show in the table?